# MIcrosoft Graph get token request failing due to CORS

Tags: oauth-2.0, ms-word, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get an access token to access one drive of the user inside the `word online add-in`. I am following the instructions on [this link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user).

I used following URL to request authorization code from within ms word online add-in which I am developing.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http://localhost/myapp/
&response_mode=query
&scope=offline_access user.read mail.read
&state=12345
```

I generate GET request with the following code:

```js
function getAuthorizationCode() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open(
    "GET",
    "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?\
  client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e\
  &response_type=code\
  &response_mode=query\
  &scope=offline_access%20user.read%20mail.read\
  &state=12345",
    true
  );

  xhr.send();
  xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", processRequest, false);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = processRequest;

  function processRequest(e) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    }
  }
}
```

But server is throwing error saying 
`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.`

If the above link is copied and pasted into the browser it works fine.
What should I do? Is there any other way to get access token inside MS Word Online add-in.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. Your question is lacking sufficient detail to help the community help you.

Comment: On generated code missing the *redirect_uri* where the token authorization endpoint redirect the flow with the code.

Comment: @Max It is still not working after adding `&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000` parameter

Comment: Try to use the microsoft javascript library [MSAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) and [SPA example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi-v2). You can learn more on this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-libraries).

Comment: What kind of Word Add-in are you building? Is it a Web Add-in (`office.js`)?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT Yes,I am building add-in for word online using office.js

Answer (score -1):

Office Web Add-ins include support for pulling a token based on the application user. This provides an SSO experience and eliminates the need to have them re-authenticate using the same credentials that they've already logged into the application with.

You can read about this functionality at [Enable single sign-on for Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins).

Comment: I had already tried that 2 days ago but it is also not working. Call to `getAccessTokenAsync` throws error. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48666289/office-context-auth-getaccesstokenasync-throws-api-not-supported-while-developin) thread.