# Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync throws API not supported while developing Microsoft Word online add-in

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js

I am trying to develop an add-in for Microsoft Word Online. I am using `Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync` call to get access token of a user, but it throws

```
error: Object { 
    name: "API Not Supported", 
    message: "This browser does not support the requested API.", 
    code: 5009 
}
status: "failed"
```

Can anyone help?

Here is code that I am using to get Token.

```
"use strict";
(function() {
  // The initialize function is run each time the page is loaded.
  Office.initialize = function(reason) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // Use this to check whether the API is supported in the Word client.
      if (Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported("WordApi", 1.1)) {
        // Do something that is only available via the new APIs
        $("#buttonPressed").click(getToken);
      } else {
        // Just letting you know that this code will not work with your version of Word.
        $("#supportedVersion").html("This code requires Word 2016 or greater.");
      }
    });
  };
  function getToken() {
    if (Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported("IdentityAPI", 1.1)) {
      console.log("Yes Identity API is supported");
      // code to request an SSO token.
      Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync(function(result) {
        if (result.status === "succeeded") {
          var token = result.value.accessToken;
          console.log(token);
        } else {
          console.log("Error obtaining token", result.error);
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.log(" ID API not supported.");
    }
  }
})();
```

My manifest code placed above `</VersionOverrides>`

```
<WebApplicationInfo>
  <Id> <My App ID is here> </Id>
  <Resource>api://localhost:3000/<My App ID is here></Resource>
  <Scopes>
    <Scope>Files.Read.All</Scope>
    <Scope>offline_access</Scope>
    <Scope>openid</Scope>
    <Scope>profile</Scope>        
  </Scopes>
</WebApplicationInfo>
```

Also tried

```
<Resource>https://localhost:3000</Resource>
```

in above code.

Comment: There isn't enough information to go on here. Without seeing the code you're using to call, understanding how your registration is set up and which environment your using it is really difficult to sort out what could be going on.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT I have added minimal code example for your reference. Please help, I have already wasted 7 days on this :-(

Comment: The code looks fine but this only a small part of the setup. You also need to make changes to your manifest and register the application. Can you add those as well?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT Done

Comment: What about the registration (where you're `AppId` is coming from)?

Comment: from [https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164782/discussion-between-aaryan-and-marc-lafleur-msft).